# Reading the state of variable in a Python program from another program

Tags: python

I have a main program in *mypy.py* which is an infinite loop to increment a variable.

```
#mypy.py
import time
def main():
    global var_a
    var_a = 0
    while True:
        var_a += 1
        time.sleep(3)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

and another program *read.py* which I want to call sporadically to read the current value of `var_a` from *mypy.py*
and I want to read the value of `var_a` through another python program sporadically.

```
#read.py
def main():
    #somehow read var_a from mypy.py
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Can u pls elaborate on what you wish to achieve?

Comment: I am just trying to learn how to do it. A possible use case is, I start a script and keep it running in a terminal, and whenever I want to see the current status of some registers, I can read them through another python script.